# Async function call not complete in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to work with some async functions but my code, for example this.saveAsCSV(lists,"lists.csv"); seems to continue before the function completes. This is not exactly what I am doing but it is the shortened version that shows my issue. console.log(lists) has the correct data but I assume it is evaluated after the call

```
   public render(): void {
    (async () => {  
      await this.GetListsBySiteID("6a368204-0534-4ffb-8014-157524ca9d50").then(lists => {
        console.log(lists);
        this.saveAsCSV(lists,"lists.csv");      
      });
    })();
  }

  async GetListsBySiteID(id:string):Promise<string[]>
  {
    let lists1:string[] = [];

    await pnp.sp.site.openWebById(id).then(result => 
    {
      result.web.lists.get().then(lists => 
      {
        lists.forEach(list => {
          lists1.push(list.Title);
        });      
      })
    });

    return lists;
  }
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: lists object in this.saveAsCSV comes through as empty

Comment: Its not a good practice to call apis inside `render` hook. Also, we don't `.then` when we `async-await`

Comment: render  hook because it is an example

Comment: You say both `lists object ... comes through as empty` and `console.log(lists) has the correct data`. One of those must be false.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://dev.to/mkamranhamid/using-useeffect-effectively-2722) article. It has good examples on how you can call apis using the react hooks

Comment: Yes palaѕн to both your questions

Comment: you are missing a return in RETURN result.web (or an await) (which would allow you to sync your promises)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not tested, but this is the idea:

1. Return a promise in the `GetListsBySiteID` function
2. resolve the promise after you have the `lists` value populated

```
GetListsBySiteID(id:string):Promise<string[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let lists:string[] = [];
      pnp.sp.site.openWebById(id).then(result => 
      {
        result.web.lists.get().then(lists => 
        {
          lists.forEach(list => {
            lists.push(list.Title);
          });    

          resolve(lists);
        })
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      reject(ex);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: what's the idea?

Comment: Return a promise int the `GetListsBySiteID` function  with the `lists` result

Comment: As mentioned, the above code is just a small reproduction of the issue. Adding the return promise and strategically placing the resolves addressed my issue, even in my bigger project

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your `GetListsBySiteID()` function you have this code:

```
await pnp.sp.site.openWebById(id).then(result => 
{
  result.web.lists.get().then(lists => 
  {
    lists.forEach(list => {
      lists.push(list.Title);
    });      
  })
});
```

So what happens here is JavaScript is `await`ing for the `pnp.sp.site.openWebById(id)` Promise to complete before continuing. You have attached the `.then()` callback so it's being `await`ed too. **Now the problem is in your `.then()` callback:**

You are calling `result.web.lists.get().then()` but this Promise is not being `await`ed for. The solution is to add `return` keyword, like this:

```
await pnp.sp.site.openWebById(id).then(result => 
{
  return result.web.lists.get().then(lists =>  // <-- here I added return
  {
    lists.forEach(list => {
      lists.push(list.Title);
    });      
  })
});
```

So now the `await` will cause JavaScript to wait for the nested Promise also.

Comment: The initial code had an error.The string array is lists1. when I do the return as you recommend it gives back the SP.List items, not the array

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full async/await solution to this issue. Using `await` on `result.web.lists.get()` will wait for the process to finish first and then when resolved, finally giving you the correct `lists`

```
public render(): void {
  (async() => {
    const lists = await this.GetListsBySiteID("6a368204-0534-4ffb-8014-157524ca9d50")
    console.log(lists);
    this.saveAsCSV(lists, "lists.csv");
  })();
}

async GetListsBySiteID(id:string):Promise<string[]> {
  let lists1: string[] = [];
  const result = await pnp.sp.site.openWebById(id)
  const lists = await result.web.lists.get()
  lists1 = lists.map(x => x.Title);
  return lists1;
}
```

Please note that in your post, you are returning `lists` at the end inside `GetListsBySiteID` and that variable is not defined inside the function. So, if you want to return `lists1` instead simply replace `return lists;` with `return lists1;`.